# How to check whether a mutex lock have been destroyed or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a problem where my code tries to call `pthread_mutex_destory()` twice. I need to check whether the lock have been destroyed before or not.

How can I do this? Will this work:

```
void deinit()
{
    if(1 == pthread_mutex_trylock(&this->m_lock))
    {
        (void) pthread_mutex_destroy(&this->m_lock);
    }
}
```

Will `trylock` only check weather the mutex is locked or not or will it also show me weather it is deleted or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you destroy a a c object, the data left behind is garbage. c++ doesn't let you do this. (It does but you have to explicitly ask for it.) But you are using a c library, so you have to do everything yourself.

So you have a few options:

- use std::mutex which works nicely with c++. But as such, you mutex will have the same lifetime as your containing class. (which is neates)
- only use `pthread_mutex_destroy` in your destructor. Same result as above. You mutex is destroyed as you object is destroyed, which happens exactly once.
- use an `std::optional` to shield the mutex data if it is not initialized.
  Wouldn't recommend, as it is an ugly mix of c and  c++.
- use a bool to keep track whether you mutex is inited.
  This is also tricky and ugly as it is prone to mistakes.

I cannot be more specific because i don't know the rest of the code.

Comment: I am going to use `std::mutex` it is the logical thing to do. However right now I have a legacy code and I want to synchronize everything before converting into the standard library. I thought about using it in my destructor but for some other reason I cant use my constructor and I'm afraid creating the object on my `init` function (which can be called multiple times) and deleting it on my destructor can cause some weird behaviours. I think I got my answer tho. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is that C++ doesn't let you do?  It isn't clear what "this" refers to.

Comment: C++ goes by the Resource allocation is initialization pricniple. This means that once you allocate memory, it is immediately initialized, and in a valid state. The same goes for destruction. It is deinitialized just before the memory is freed. So if you destroy a c++ object, the data is immediately deallocated as wel

Answer (score 1):

> I need to check whether the lock have been destroyed before or not.
>
> How can I do this?

You *can't* affirmatively do it.  That is, there is no way to examine a `pthread_mutex_t` object to determine whether it is initialized.  `pthread_mutex_init()` is not useful for the purpose, and mutex functions other than `pthread_mutex_init()` have defined behavior only if the mutex is initialized.

You *could* maintain a separate atomic flag that indicates whether the mutex is initialized, but it is usually best to structure the program so that it is not possible for multiple threads to try to destroy the same mutex.  One way that is sometimes viable is simply to avoid destroying them explicitly at all.

> Will `trylock` only check weather the mutex is locked or not or will it also show me weather it is deleted or not?

The behavior of `pthread_mutex_trylock()` is undefined when the provided pointer does not point to a valid, initialized mutex object. Therefore no, you cannot rely on it to detect whether a mutex has been destroyed.

More generally, there is no safe way to destroy a mutex that may still be contended.  Before you destroy a mutex, you need to ensure by some means -- typically the structure of the program -- that there is no possibility of any thread trying to access the mutex during or after its destruction.  You cannot rely on the mutex itself for that.